# My buttons and texts are showing in the wrong places on Android Studio 4.0

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, figma

Hi I'm practicing clickable button, for that, I need to reproduce the design here:
https://www.figma.com/file/pAx28mFg68qvYulJQcyMHE/Score-Tracker?node-id=0%3A1

But for some reason, although I believe I wrote all the dimensions right, I can't get to position the buttons and zeros in the exact place they should be in and I don't know why!

Here is my xml code. Can you help me find out what's wrong with the dimensions I have set?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@drawable/background">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:src="@drawable/background"/>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/numberOfGoals"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="163dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="124dp"
                android:text="0"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textSize="72sp"/>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/numberOfGoals2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="163dp"
                android:layout_alignTop="@id/Button2"
                android:layout_marginBottom="124dp"
                android:text="0"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textSize="72sp"/>
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/Button1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Goal"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
                android:backgroundTint="#EB5757"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/Button2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Goal"
                android:backgroundTint="#EB5757"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="14dp"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

May be this will be helpful.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@drawable/background">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:src="@drawable/background"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/numberOfGoals"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/Button1"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:text="0"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textSize="72sp"/>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/numberOfGoals2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_above="@id/Button2"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:text="0"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textSize="72sp"/>
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/Button1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Goal"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
                android:backgroundTint="#EB5757"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/Button2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Goal"
                android:backgroundTint="#EB5757"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="14dp"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help I simply changed the dimensions and it looked fine ( I thought I had to stick to the numbers in figma but it turns out I can adjust them to fit right in my emulator screen). But I will also try your suggestion and check the result. Thanks